# Google Sheet/App Script - Gantt Chart: move pinned row on current date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gantt-chart

I have created a gantt chart like in the screenshot below. Data will be entered every day. I need to make that when Monday comes of each new week, the cell pinned is shifted (in other words, the first cell would be every new Monday of the week, but it would be possible to scroll back to view past info) to this date. Or on date, which will be set in cell E1 every week/day.
Can you help me with this question?

Example:
First week [Image week 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mW44.png)

Second week [Image week 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB7Ta.png)

Third week [Image week 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arCmY.png)

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, clearly indicating the expected output?

Comment: @iamblichus Yes, this is link to my list https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vhjj21ppu5LJxTc7y6HxjMDYIzZy6feB5lXIs4hGYsc/edit#gid=0
Red fill - current date. I need, when current date will be 17.05 (orange fill), it will be first row cell after pin (moved to position on column F), and the previous week hide or moved for pinned, but so that later you could view the previously week entered data.
Add example, what I need, into post

Comment: The spreadsheet you provided is private and I cannot access it. Can you make it publicly accessible?

Comment: Yes, access to spreadsheet is granted